# Pgbackrest backup error with exit code 57

Tags: pgbackrest

Today I got an error for pgbackrest database backup. There was no problem for incremental and full backup for my postgresql database in nearly 3 months, and I did not change any configurations for pgbackrest or postgresql parameters.

```
time="2024-01-08T11:36:39Z" level=info msg="debug flag set to false"
time="2024-01-08T11:36:39Z" level=info msg="backrest backup command requested"
time="2024-01-08T11:36:39Z" level=info msg="command to execute is [pgbackrest backup --stanza=db --repo=1 --type=full --delta=y]"
time="2024-01-08T11:40:59Z" level=info msg="output=[]"
time="2024-01-08T11:40:59Z" level=info msg="stderr=[ERROR: [057]: raised from remote-0 tls protocol on 'od-instance1-6nqs-0.od-pods.od.svc.cluster.local.': unable to execute query 'select lsn::text as lsn,\n pg_catalog.pg_walfile_name(lsn)::text as wal_segment_name\n from pg_catalog.pg_start_backup('pgBackRest backup started at ' || current_timestamp, false, false) as lsn': server closed the connection unexpectedly\n \tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n \tbefore or while processing the request.\n invalid socket\n]"
time="2024-01-08T11:40:59Z" level=fatal msg="command terminated with exit code 57"
```

Any comments for the cause?
Thank you.